# Optionally call .distinct() in the middle of a Streams API function call chain

Tags: java, java-stream

I cannot find a way to use the Streams API **and** to have a short conditional addition to the 'pipeline' of an aggregate operation like a .distinct() call.

The following code shows how I have to duplicate the .filter call after the conditional .distinct() call, making the code more verbose than I'd like:

```java
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
Supplier<Stream<NodeXType>> nodexSupplier = () -> myXMLPayload.getNodeXs().stream();
// Avoid BUG where the NodeXs are duplicated in the Payload XML impacting tests.
if (NODE_X.length < nodexSupplier.get().filter(e -> e.getSubTypeofNode_X().equalsIgnoreCase("myTargetValue")).count()){
   LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "had more sub-type values than expected, so removed duplicates");
   nodexSupplier.get()
       .distinct()
       .filter(e -> e.getSubTypeofNode_X().equalsIgnoreCase("myTargetValue"))
       .forEachOrdered(e -> {
           assertEquals(" myTargetValue nodes not updated to expected value",
               e.getSubTypeofNode_X().getNewValue().toString(), NODE_X[index.getAndIncrement()]);
       });
} else {
   nodexSupplier.get()
       .filter(e -> e.getSubTypeofNode_X().equalsIgnoreCase("myTargetValue"))
       .forEachOrdered(e -> {
           assertEquals(" myTargetValue nodes not updated to expected value",
               e.getSubTypeofNode_X().getNewValue().toString(), NODE_X[index.getAndIncrement()]);
       });
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this, without breaking the Streams rules?
like:

```
pipelineObj =  Source.stream()    
if (condition) {pipelineObj.distinct}
pipelineObj.filter{}...
```

Comment: _without breaking the Steams rules_ What do you mean by this ? I think it's ok to add `distinct()` in the pipeline depends on the condition .

Comment: It would help if you would give a concrete example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @WJS Is this not a concrete example?

Comment: Can you just call `.distinct()` unconditionally? Is it harmful in the `else` case?

Comment: @JohnKugelman - Not exactly no, I just wanted a conditional to check for the presence of the bug and Log out its is doing something special and I could then tag it and use it's non execution to prove the bug is fixed if it gets fixed, and was surprised I couldn't do it .easily.

Comment: @WJS -  Will do if Sweepers answer doesn't work somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a utility method:

```java
static <T> Stream<T> distinctIf(Stream<T> s, boolean b) {
  return b ? s.distinct() : s;
}
```

Comment: Utility method worked and I can re-assign back to the original pipelineObj no problems. Not sure why @Sweeper 's answer isn't working. Will try again later to see if I can get that approach to work - as more succinct..

Answer (score 5):

As long as you don't do terminal operations multiple times on a single stream, it's okay to put the stream into a variable:

```
Stream<NodeXType> pipelineObj = nodexSupplier.get();
if (NODE_X.length < nodexSupplier.get().filter(e -> e.getSubTypeofNode_X().equalsIgnoreCase("myTargetValue")).count()) {
    pipelineObj = pipelineObj.distinct();
}
pipelineObj
    .filter(e -> e.getSubTypeofNode_X().equalsIgnoreCase("myTargetValue"))
    .forEachOrdered(e -> {
           assertEquals(" myTargetValue nodes not updated to expected value",
               e.getSubTypeofNode_X().getNewValue().toString(), NODE_X[index.getAndIncrement()]);
       });
```

However, you might want to do something about calling `nodexSupplier.get()` twice...

Comment: Sorry I think it should work but it isn't. I get:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed

Comment: @SystemsInCode does the supplier return the same stream if you call it multiple times? My answer is based on the assumption that `get` returns a new stream every time you call it.

Comment: its the same as  in the pseudo code which I think should return a new stream instance each time..